# Iterate through dictionary, list within list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains a list inside of lists. For example

```
d1 = {
    'first': [['soccer'], 2],
    'second': [['football'], 10],
    'third': [['basketball'], 5],
    'fourth': [['rugby'], 3]
}
```

Before I added the numbers to this dictionary I would just iterate through them like so

```
for k,v in d1.iteritems()
#Here i can separate all the keys and values as I wish
```

But now i need the numbers inside of the dictionary, so im trying to figure out how i can iterate through the current dict as is and be able to pull out the key, and the two values, 
For example if i were to try and do this

```
print k, value1, value2
# Output should be  first, soccer, 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format is consistent, you can just unpack it as you iterate through the dictionary:

```
In [5]: for k, ([sport], num) in d1.iteritems():
   ...:     print k, sport, num
   ...:
second football 10
fourth rugby 3
third basketball 5
first soccer 2
```

Comment: What does the 

    In [5]: stand for?

Comment: You can ignore the prompts. In normal python console this is just `>>>` and `...`. In the ipython console the prompt is `In [x]:` and `...:`, where x is the execution number.